# How can i change all file extention from Gif to gif?

Tags: c#

This code will rename all the files names :

```
static private void RenameFiles()
        {
            images = Directory.GetFiles(sf, "*.gif");
            foreach (string name in images)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Working on current file: " + name);
                //string newName = name.Replace("radar_temp_directory", String.Empty);
                //string newName = Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(name),Path.GetFileName(name).Replace("radar_temp_directory", String.Empty));
                string newName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(name), Path.GetFileName(name).Replace("radar_temp_directory", String.Empty));
                File.Move(name, newName);
            }
        }
```

But now i want to make another method that will change each file extention from Gif to gif.
Or if it will be "gIf" so all the extentions of the files will be .gIf
But now i want to change it to gif. So for example if i have a file radar000005.Gif it will be radar000005.gif

Comment: Does that really matter :/

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan it does if those files need to be hosted on a non-Windows server and you forgot to use the proper casing when referring to the files.

Comment: Oh, I never used the non-windows server. Thanks anyways, as I never knew that thing :)

Comment: Just use that: `File.Move(path, Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".gif"));`

Comment: Windows file systems are case-insensitive, they won't see any need at all to do anything with your code.  Of course there isn't.  You'll have to work around it by renaming the file twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following method

```
Path.ChangeExtension(string path, string newExtension);
```

The path would be the String which would be pointing to the location of the file, second parameter would be a new String Extension that would be appeneded to the filename.

#### Example code provided at MSDN

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.com.extension";
string result = "";
Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "string");
```

But remember, it won't save the file. You'll have to save the file as a new file. This would only change the fileExtension once at the run-time.

For more on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx

Comment: That's a useful helper for finding the new filename. But it doesn't touch the file at all. Some more code will be needed.

Comment: Then you must save new file physically. 
`File.Move(path, Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".gif"));`